# How to import external js file in jsp

Tags: java, eclipse, jsp

This is my folder structure

[image]

This is my jsp

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="resources/one.js"></script>
```

I get the following error

[image]

I can not understand whats going on,..
pls help

Comment: put relative path of js file  `../resources/one.js`

Comment: it is not work.i already try this one,.

Comment: Put resources folder into web-inf ?

Comment: @HuyLuu yes tried that one also

Comment: So what is your full URL?

Comment: @HuyLuu It is  http://localhost:8081/testdb/resources/one.js

Comment: try it like this, `<script type="text/javascript" src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/resources/one.js"></script>`

Comment: Try to get http context (yours is /testdb) and append to /resources/...

Comment: @LahiruAshan sorry that also not work,..

Comment: try after clearing your browser cache.

Comment: What's not working that should be working? What symptom are you experiencing?

Comment: @nitind Now I also add error in the question

Comment: are you using any framework for your project?

Comment: How are you launching this server? Is it listening on port 8081 or port 80?

Comment: yes it listening on port 8081

Comment: @nitind By setting tomcat server port

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I too Faced a similar situation and what is did was saved my External Js file as Filename.jsp and imported that as follow's and it worked.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="keybd.jsp">
```

Where keybd.jsp was keybd.js previously.

Note that my page and external js file are in the same directory.

Answer (score 0):

I also experience this kind of problem, my js and css cannot be read by my jsp's. I add many **../** and it works fine, i guess it has something to do with the number of **/** in the url. for example [How to import external js file in jsp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40121185/how-to-import-external-js-file-in-jsp) has 3 **/** after the domain that is why you need to put 3 **../**. Not sure, I just shared how do I solved same problem.

Comment: i tried 1 to 4 ../.But it was not working,.

Comment: try to put your js in a folder then map the source. <script src="../resources/newfolder/one.js"></script>